# How can I direct people from a mobile app to specifically a desktop site?

Tags: mobile, web-app, mobile-application

My issue is that I want to be able to send people from our app to a feature that is only available on the desktop version of our website. It's not available on the mobile responsive site, so tapping a "send me an email (with the link)" isn't ideal as they would likely open it on their mobile device.

Comment: So the idea is a kind of bookmark that you want to guide/nudge them into opening with a desktop computer?

Comment: Yes - I guess so.

Comment: Are you asking how to let users know a feature doesn't exist on the mobile app?

Comment: Aside from making the missing content mobile friendly and putting it in the app, I think the best you can do is messaging "Hey, there's this other cool thing you can look at later when you're at home".

Comment: If there is a need for telling people a specific feature is only available on desktop, there is a user need for the feature to be on mobile. Something you might want to consider.

Comment: Case in point: one of my co-workers a year ago owned only a smartphone, not a desktop PC. Is there a reason this feature can be made available on a 10" netbook but not a 10" tablet, such as extensive text entry? The nature of this reason may help us understand how to phrase such a reminder.

Answer (score 1):

"Access our desktop site for this information" with "desktop site" being a specific link to desktop, assuming you can force the desktop site to load.

That way you give up the link, but let users know it's on desktop - they can decide if they want to open it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you could add some kind of reminder/push notification system into your app? Something along the lines of: "To get the most of our service, use x feature on the desktop." Then have a button "Remind me" with a date and time selector to pick when this reminder should be pushed to him/her?